Which camera setting is used in sony cameras to capture continuous light along with flash light
I want to capture led lighting in some part of furniture and also want flash light in single image. How can we do that in sony cameras? I don’t want to merge two images in photoshop.

There is nothing special about recording an LED with flash... it is the same as recording no light along with flash, incandescent light with flash, or daylight with flash. All flash images are in effect a double exposure, ambient plus flash (whichever is brighter is "on top").
The main thing you will want to do is use a long enough ambient exposure so as to avoid recording the LED pulses/banding. A longer SS will also allow more of the LED exposure to build up which will be necessary to avoid being buried by the flash exposure.
IMO, your best bet is to start with the LED exposure (settings) to get the effect/amount/exposure you want, then add the flash on top (TTL/fill).

On any camera, regardless of the brand or model, the process is a combination of aperture and shutter speed. Therefore use Manual mode.

Use a tripod.

Define a relatively closed aperture, let's say f/11 This aperture is defined in combination with your flash power. This combination is the one that exposes the flash.
Make these initial tests using the sync speed of your camera, for example, 1/200.

As the aperture is small, you now need a slow shutter speed to expose the surrounding natural light, which is far less intense than the flash. Depending on the scene it could be let's say 1/2 second or whatever you need.




As an additional tip use the ISO setting on the lowest number, this way you will provoke the need to use longer times on the shutter speed.


When you combine continuous and flash lighting the general rule is that your aperture controls the exposure from the flash and the shutter speed (when it is slow enough) the one from the continuous light.
